# Comment section not appearing on posts

Tags: comments, comment-form

My comment section simply does not appear on posts, even though on my first couple test posts, it did appear.

The current theme I'm using is Tesseract, in case that is relevant. Before that I was using Urban Bold, which did not work out for me, despite having the comment section, initially. I have already tried out other themes too, and reverting back to Urban Bold just out of curiosity. They don't have the comment section either now.

I have gone through all the settings and made sure that the comment section is available. I have also attempted to turn off all my plugins to see if they were causing the problem, but the comment section was still missing after that.

Here is the [first blog post](http://northernconservative.com/2015/11/06/we-cant-pretend-conservative-loss-isnt-self-inflicted-pt-1/) of the website in case you would like to see it.

**Update:** Since I referenced my blog on this post, I got a notification of a comment to be approved about it being referenced in this post. For the purpose of testing, I approved it and other than that one comment it simply says the comment section is closed, even though all the settings should dictate otherwise. Does any of this point to a solution to the problem?

**Update 2:** As an admin, I can also enter comments through editing the post. It appears on the post, but the comments on the post itself for the readers remain closed as [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb88k.jpg).

Comment: Have you gone thorough **wp-admin/options-discussion.php** settings, might be something there to change to enable comments.

Comment: Yup :( I've gone through it so much now, the only reason it is not only on default settings is because I've been messing around with it so much to get the comment section to work. Am I missing anything? http://imgur.com/oeZ8hKt

Comment: Settings looks alright.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Comments_in_WordPress 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Discussion_Screen
https://codex.wordpress.org/Comment_Moderation

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I have no idea what went wrong originally. I just deleted and reposted the blog post and the comment section miraculously started working.

Go figure. Hopefully it will be a smooth sailing from now on.